# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory cant solve this

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-support-library, androidx

i am new in android and have an app that when build my project have this Error ::

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86   is also
>   present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).  Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-44:19 to override.

My Gradle build  is ::

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "maa.tic_tac_to"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    // implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.+'
    // implementation ('com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'){

       // exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    //}
    // implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha08'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta2'
    // implementation 'com.androidx.constraintlayout.widget:ConstraintLayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="maa.tic_tac_to">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/tic_tac_toe"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MySMSReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".FakeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LogInActivity"></activity>


        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i test every solution in stackoverflow and google search but anyone help me.
can anyone help to solve this error ?!?!?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
```

Firebase migrated to AndroidX in the latest release. 
It means that you are using both, support libraries and androidx libraries.

You can:

- migrate to androidx as described below
- downgrade your firebase dependencies (but it is not a real solution because you have to migrate sooner or later)

You can check the [official release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019):

> **Warning:** This release is a **MAJOR** version update and breaking change.
>   The latest update to Google Play services and Firebase includes the following changes:

Migration from Android Support Libraries to Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries. Libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to v3.2.1 or later.
- **Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or later.**
- Update your app **to use Jetpack (AndroidX)**; follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: thanks Bro i Migrate to AndroidX and change the imports to AndroidX and its works now

Comment: Hi @hossein. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this