# About Sdk and firebase

Tags: android

when i add these lines of firebase in andriod studio i got these errors

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rashid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0] C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\db323219c95310ba498dc7530caba4e9\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
>       Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
>           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
>           or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.iid" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Comment: Maybe you're new in android dev. Basically the error is right, you've to declare all the dependencies not smaller then minSDK version. Like you're using minSDK 15 and the firebase library is built on SDK < 15 due to that you're getting compatibility issue.

Comment: yes i am new, then how to solve this

Comment: In my upper comment i did some mistake "firebase library is built on SDK > 15". The solution for your issue is to update your minSDK > 15 and then update the libraries on basis of it. From my perspective change minSDK to 21 and targetSDK and compileSDK not more then 28 otherwise you'll get AndroidX issues.

Comment: SIr i try ,but cant not resolve this issue.I am fixing this issue from two days. But failed

Comment: can you please update your post and share gradle code so, it would be easy for us to respond

Comment: @MuhammadRashid Pls report your full build.gradle. It is incomplete and the issue is in the dependencies list

Answer (score 0):

This is a small fix. In you build gradle (app), there should be a line of code that says:

```
minSDK 15
```

Change that 15 to a 16 or 17 and then it should work.

Comment: problem not solved ,when i update it to 16 or 17.i got another error

Comment: This Error    ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.

Comment: Add this implementation `'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' `dependency and
Remove this dependency implementation ` 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` from module level gradle file. If this doesnt work, add `'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to your manifest. You also could migrate the whole project to andriodx

Comment: i try all methods but cant not resolve this issue. i am trying to fix this issue from two days

Comment: The 17.0.0 version has been buggy for me in the past. Try 17.0.1

Comment: can i disscuss the isssue on my email. I will be thanfull of your help

Comment: @MuhammadRashid It is a different error. You are mixing support libraries and androidx libraries. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022157/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-cant-solve-th/57022608#57022608  Next time pls post your full build.gradle