# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application

Tags: android, kotlin

i try builiding my app but it errors out like this

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-53:19 to override.

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Comment: Probably you are using both support library and androidx library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory cant solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022157/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-cant-solve-th)

Answer (score -1):

This generally happens when you use AndroidX with legacy support dependencies.
Try adding following in gradle.properties file:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```