# Error when Adding Firebase to Android App Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, firebase

I am setting up Firebase on my App, I have done the following:

Registered the App
Downloaded the google-services.json file and inserted in my Android app module root directory
Modified my Gradle files

However, when I try to Sync with Gradle I get the following error

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-118:19 to override.

When I insert `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` in my Manifest file, I get the following error

ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

I can't seem to find why or where the error is coming from as I followed the Android setup tutorial judiciously and did not make any error

Here is my App Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ariellafitness"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'co.paystack.android.design.widget:pinpad:1.0.1'
    implementation 'co.paystack.android:paystack:3.0.10'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Here is part of my Project Gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I will appreciate your help

Comment: you need migrate to AndroidX

Comment: @Ticherhaz thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at here. It seems that the problem is same

[Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory cant solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022157/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-cant-solve-th?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, I hade to upgrade to Android X